# How to export Intellij project as Eclipse archived folder

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

My professor wants all assignments submitted as an archived folder and wants the program to be able to run on his Eclipse when he grades them. The program is a simple one with one folder that has to contain just one class with the main method.

I am using IntelliJ.

I followed Jetbrains faq on exporting files as Eclipse-compatible using Files --> Export : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exporting-an-intellij-idea-project-to-eclipse.html

It looks like the files were successfully converted as my folder directory looks similar to what the website. A screenshot of my directory after exporting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzi6F.jpg

I am not sure what to do here as I am not familiar with the Eclipse ".classpath" and ".project" files that were created as well as the .eml and .iml files. I don't know what to do with them.

I was thinking of just copying them into a new folder called "ReviewNW" and archiving them and submitting that folder. I don't know if that would be enough for Eclipse to run my program. Is there something else I have to do from here?

Additional question: I have since changed some things in my program. Now when I try to use File --> Export, IntelliJ gives me an error and says I "cannot export files already exported to eclipse-compatible format". What if I make some changes to my class files in my src folder and need to export those changes again? I think I would need to manually delete each of those Eclipse files and export again or is there a simpler way?

Thank you!

Comment: It is enough for Eclipse to run your program. Classpath and .project are Eclipse configuration files.

Comment: Once you exported project to Eclipse, you don't need to do it again. Just edit your files, and once ready - archive the project's folder. All Eclipse configuration files are already in place.

Comment: Be aware that by doing so, there might be issues that your professor will see, but that will not even displayed to you.